# Passing a receipt to iCloud

Tags: objective-c, ios7, icloud, rmstore

I am using RMStore's app receipt to verify a non-renewing subscription . When I try to send this receipt to iCloud I get an error : *** -[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '' of class 'RMAppReceipt'.

Here is the code :

```
 RMAppReceipt *receipt = [RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt];
 NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *storage = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
 [storage setObject:receipt forKey:@"iReceipt"];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: RMAppReceipt is subclass of NSObject : @interface RMAppReceipt : NSObject

Comment: Search on the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+Attempt+to+insert+non-property+value You need to follow the same rules as you would for `NSUserDefaults` or property lists.

Comment: In addition to what @rmaddy said, the bundle receipt can be `nil` in certain scenarios. Try refreshing it first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by creating an array from properties inside and sent an array to iCloud.